# Get coordinates on tapping map in android

Tags: android, dictionary, touch, coordinates, tap

I'm trying to make something like this: I have a mapactivity and when the user taps the map it shows the coordinates of that location. I already overrided the onclick method but it isn't even called. Any Idea?

```
public class MapPoint extends MapActivity implements OnClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mappoints);

    MapView map = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapview);
    map.setOnClickListener(this);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.getController().setZoom(18);
    map.getController().setCenter(new GeoPoint(39735007, -8827330));


}

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
}
```

}

Comment: [this will help sure..](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9477079/1151312)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try the following.

Write a class which derives from the [Overlay](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html) class and override the [onTap()](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/Overlay.html#onTap%28com.google.android.maps.GeoPoint,%20com.google.android.maps.MapView%29) method. Then you can add your overlay to the your [MapView](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/MapView.html). A [GeoPoint](http://code.google.com/intl/de-DE/android/add-ons/google-apis/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.html) object, which represents the position of you tap, is passed to the onTap() method when you tab somewhere on the map.

Answer (score 7):

`onClick()` is not used here. You will need to override `onTouchEvent()`. [Here is a sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Maps/NooYawkTouch/) showing using `onTouchEvent()` to drag and drop `ItemizedOverlay` map pins.

Given the screen coordinates of the touch, you can use a `Projection` (from `getProjection()` on `MapView`) to convert that to latitude and longitude.

Answer (score 4):

The modern answer, using Android Maps v2, is to use OnMapClickListener, which gives you the LatLng of a tap on the map.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener.html

Comment: link is not valid anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I put some details of my implementation in this question:
[How do I respond to a tap on an Android MapView, but ignore pinch-zoom?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806061/how-do-i-respond-to-a-tap-on-an-android-mapview-but-ignore-pinch-zoom)

The problem I found with using onTap() is that it also gets fired when you pinch-zoom, which was not what my app needed. So if you need pinch-zoom, my code should do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private class OverlayMapa extends Overlay {

 @Override
 public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow) 
 {
   ...
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onTap(GeoPoint point, MapView mapView) 
 {
   Context contexto = mapView.getContext();
   String msg = "Lat: " + point.getLatitudeE6()/1E6 + " - " + 
                "Lon: " + point.getLongitudeE6()/1E6;

   Toast toast = Toast.makeText(contexto, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
   toast.show();

  return true;
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like @CommonsWare said, you need to use `onTouch()` function and not `onClick()`. Here is an example, this is exactly what you need : http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android