# Android tap on map and get coordinates

Tags: android, overlay, coordinates, android-mapview, google-maps-markers

I am trying to make an app that once the user taps on a map it gets the coordinates of that specific point.

Among others I have also read that: [Get coordinates on tapping map in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177305/get-coordinates-on-tapping-map-in-android)

It seems like the most relevant post but what I want to do is to be able to tap anywhere on the map not on an marker/overlay item. In fact I want to create a marker in that specific point that the user tapped and get the coordinates of it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

Should be trivial with a little bit of math. You can use `getLatitudeSpan()` and `getLongitudeSpan()` to get the extents of the visible map, and `getMapCenter()` to see the center point. Just map that to the coordinates of the touch event.

EDIT: Mark, as always, has an even more elegant solution.

Comment: Actually, this one came from a reader contribution, so I can't take full credit.