# How to get coordinates by tapping google map

Tags: android

I'm developing an Location based reminder for android using gps. I want to obtain the co-ordinates of a particular location by tapping a map. i am unable to find a fitting solution to this problem. Can anybody pls help?
 Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Get coordinates on tapping map in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177305/get-coordinates-on-tapping-map-in-android/4177676#4177676)