# android how to get temprature of location on  mapview

Tags: android, android-mapview

all 
android is new for me , so i just want to know that
is it possible to get temperature of particular location on  mapview ?

In my application i want to show temperature of location when user tap on map.
so it can happen then please help..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible:

1. When user taps on map you can get the location of the point: [Get coordinates on tapping map in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4177305/get-coordinates-on-tapping-map-in-android)
2. Query an online Weather service to get temperatures for given location: for example [Yahoo Weather](http://developer.yahoo.com/weather/)
3. Show popup on map that tells the temperature: [Show popup above map marker in MapView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707923/show-popup-above-map-marker-in-mapview)

Answer (score 3):

In order to find the temp, fetch info from a weather API like Yahoo's and match it to the device's location.

Answer (score 1):

There is no by default API for this under google maps API. You need to search for any separate weather API's which provide temperature data based on locations.