# Disable onMarkerClickListener completely in Maps API v2

Tags: android, onclick, maps, marker

I want to disable clicking/tapping on `map markers`. I know you can `disable default behavior` by setting up an empty `map.setOnMarkerClickListener` and return true; However, this still takes the tap as clicking on the marker. I want to pass the tap on to the `onMapClickListener`.

In my app, tapping the map moves a marker around, and if you're tapping close to where the marker is already, it just thinks you're tapping the marker! You would think there is a `Marker.setClickable` method but there isn't.

Comment: @Patrick No I did not.

Comment: I found the solution in this post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497734/dont-snap-to-marker-after-click-in-android-map-v2
basically return true and call onMapClick on it's listener.  Works for me.

Comment: @Patrick that seems to work but it isn't perfect. Here's why. You have a marker. You tap near it, onMarkerClick gets triggered, passes it on to onMapClick. However, it passes the marker.getPosition() to onMapClick, not the actual tap position. So tapping anywhere near a marker is the same as tapping on that marker. How do I get the real position of the tap?

Comment: oohh.  Had not realized that.  off the top of my head I don't know.

Comment: Pretty much the exact same issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884401/google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-non-clickable

Comment: Hello, i look many things about it but i basically solved this by running the method which should run on mapclick at markerclick. It solved. Simple. You should try it

Comment: @alicanbatur as said above - you don't know which pixel of marker was clicked, you can only use marker position

Comment: @Flyview - Did you figure out a solution? I want to do the same thing, handle map click rather than marker click events.

Comment: @Justin no unfortunately I never did. I would have posted an answer! Please do if you figure it out.

Comment: @Flyview, I do have a solution for this. See my comment on a duplicate question over at: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41867025/1669870

Answer (score 9):

Just override the onclick event:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i have two suggestions:

if i understood right, you want to offer the functionality to place a marker on the map, right?! If you cannot remove the `setOnMarkerClickListener`, did you tried to [draw](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle) at the map and "convert" your drawing to a `Marker` in the end. (get 'LatLng' from drawing and create a `Marker`).

actually the second suggestion isn't really a good one (depending if you can zoom/move your map). I had a similar task and we used an transparent overlay over the map, which handled all user input and delegates it. but we didn`t had the functionality of zoom and move, which would be pain in the ass...

Comment: No, I am not trying to put a marker on the map. I am trying to disable google's onMarkerClickListener and pass the tap to onMapClickListener.

Answer (score -1):

`map.setOnMarkerClickListener(null);` try this

Comment: Doesn't work. It's as if you don't set your own listener at all and default behavior takes over.

Answer (score -1):

```
class MyInfoWindowAdapter implements GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter
{
     @Override
     public View getInfoContents(Marker mar)
     {
         return null;
     }
     @Override
     public View getInfoWindow(Marker mar)
     {
         return null;
     }
}
```

`gmap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new MyInfoWindowAdapter);`

Try this code above. This will set your infowindow to null.

Comment: This answer is wrong. Setting a custom ``InfoWindowAdapter`` to return null just means the default ``InfoWindowAdapter`` is used. This results in stock behavior.

Answer (score -1):

Apply `OnMarkerClickListener`to your map. Implement `onMarkerClick()`method and return`false`

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: It's better to return `true` to consume the event and override the behavior.

Answer (score -3):

It is not necessary to implement OnMarkerClickListner. Just try to remove this statement

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListner(this)
```

from your code and I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: No, this does not work. The default onMarkerClick behavior takes over.

Comment: try overriding this method and do not call super, so that default method can be avoided

Comment: I did not call the super.

Comment: The way you implement this method, you always override the method. There is no calling of the super either. Therefore, yes, from the beginning I had tried this and it does not work, sorry.