# Google Maps API v2: How to make markers non-clickable?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps, android-maps-v2

I mean if i click marker `OnMarkerClickListener` is called, so the `OnMapClickListener` did not. Even if i set `mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(null);` marker object still masks all click events for underlying map and objects.
How can i set `Marker` transparent for all user interractions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is indeed a "limitation" of markers as of 3.1.59 version of the library.

If you really need them to be markers, please post a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2) for `MarkerOptions.clickable` and `Marker.setClickable`.

If you can, consider using other visual objects, e.g. `GroundOverlay`. The only problem is they all scale with map, unlike markers. The closest would be `Circle` with zero radius and 20-50 dp stroke width, but that's only a single color dot.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_a_marker) about markers, if you add your own Listener and the onMarkerClick() method returns false, the default behaviour will be executed.

So, in the onMarkerClick() just return true and do nothing else to completely overwrite the default.

Comment: My tried `onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {return true;}` but `onMapClick` is still not called. I think docs's explanation means that if I return `true` no default behavior will occure (infoWindow), only my code, wich i post in `onMarkerClick`

Comment: Try this: in onMarkerClick add the line `onMapClick(marker.getPosition());`

Comment: I thought about it. In this case would be a great error. I will do this way if no other solution would be not found

Comment: Well the problem is if you click the marker the onMapClick will not be triggered.

Answer (score 3):

The only workaround I found for this issue is to execute the same code in `OnMarkerClickListener` that you have in `OnMapClickListener` and return `false`:

```
getMap().setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {

    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        onMapClick(marker.getPosition());
        return true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work because onMarkerClick gives you the location of the marker that it determines is closest to where you clicked, not where you actually clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can skip setting `Marker.Title` and in this case the marker won't be clickable. Use `Marker.Tag` if you need to associate some data (like id or name) with the marker without an ability for end-user to tap and see that.

Answer (score -1):

Make your class implementing Google Maps implement OnMarkerClickListener, i.e.:

```
public class GoogleMapFragment extends Fragment implements MapImplementation, OnMapReadyCallback,
    GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener, GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {
```

and then implement method inside:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(@NonNull Marker marker) {
        // Make Marker not clickable in practice
        return true;
    }
```