# Label at the top of the marker in google maps api v2

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview, android-maps-v2

One more problem while switching to the maps api v2.
This is an ugly representation of what i want to achieve.

Edit1. There can be several markers, every marker with its own label. All markers and labels are shown simultaneously.

[image]

As you can see there is a label with some information at the top of the marker.
While using api v1 it can easily be done with drawing marker and label on `Overlay`.

How can I implement it using api v2?

The first idea is to render marker(red) and label(black) to one bitmap and set it as marker. But it will significantly increase marker area(red rectangle) and with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17887439/1562477)  marker limitation gives me real headache with user to map interraction realisation.

The second idea is to use `GroundOverlay`, but at first glance, it is not designed for this purpose.

Edit2 [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331983/multiple-info-windows-in-android-maps-api-2) is similar question, solution, like in the first idea, is to use both marker and label as single marker bitmap, created from view.

Comment: I think that here you have an answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15040761/2075875

Comment: I have seen it. That wrapper used to provide custom view-like behavior. Please, look at my comment below

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at a library I am working on:
[googlemaps/android-maps-utils](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils)

You can use the [`BubbleIconFactory`](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/ui/BubbleIconFactory.html) to achieve this:

[image: BubbleIconFactory]

```
IconGenerator factory = new IconGenerator(this);
Bitmap icon = factory.makeIcon("11:15 1.08.2013");

mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(...).
    icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(icon)));
```

Comment: awesome! save me times 

Answer (score 1):

This is much simpler to do on Android Maps v2. Please take a look at the official documentation here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

It is called Info Window. By default, an info window is displayed when a user taps on a marker and **if the marker has a title set**

Comment: Key phrase is `when they tap on a marker on a map.` I need to show this label on the top of several markers independely whether user clicks them or not.

Comment: for that purpose I use custom dialog which popups above the clicked item.

Comment: I have changed question to mention this moment.