# How to show a label next to a marker on Google maps on Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am working on an Android app which uses Google maps Android API.I am showing multiple markers on the map and I want to show a label next to each marker as shown in the image below but I'm unable to find out how to do it.

[image: Image with google map marker and label]

I have gone through the Google maps documentation at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/map-with-marker
but I am unable to find details on how to show the label in this manner.I have tried the title property which opens up a popup but I need that to show a detailed view(InfoWindow) about my markers and I need to show the main title without opening the popup for any marker

Any idea how I can add a marker in the manner shown in attached image?

Comment: you can check these https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17989389/label-at-the-top-of-the-marker-in-google-maps-api-v2

Comment: @NavjotSingh: I have seen these.The title property shows only when user clicks on the marker

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you had in mind, but here goes

Create the `MarkerOptions` object:

```
MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .title(name)
                .position(source)
                .icon(gettIconFromDrawable(myMarker))
                .snippet("Briefly describe \nyour content here");
```

Then add the marker to the map

```
Marker sourceMarker = mMap.addMarker(options);
```

Create `InfoWindowAdapter` to accommodate multiple lines in the snippet. *(Original [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31852074/6891637) here)*

```
mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                Context context = getApplicationContext(); //or getActivity(), YourActivity.this, etc.

                LinearLayout info = new LinearLayout(context);
                info.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

                TextView title = new TextView(context);
                title.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                title.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
                title.setText(marker.getTitle());

                TextView snippet = new TextView(context);
                snippet.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
                snippet.setText(marker.getSnippet());

                info.addView(title);
                info.addView(snippet);

                return info;
            }
        });
```

Finally, add this property to ensure the marker stays visible

```
sourceMarker.showInfoWindow();
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But actually I have mentioned in the question that I am already using the infoWindow to show a customised and detailed View about the marker object. I need to show one line label for all markers on the map which should be visible without clicking on the markers

Comment: Thats what the `sourceMarker.showInfoWindow();` bit is supposed to do

Comment: But my requirement is slightly different. There has to be a label visible for all  markers and clicking on a marker should show the detailed infoWindow with details of that marker

Comment: Hi @AkshitRewari did you found solution. If you found solution then could you share it?