# Google map v2 make infowindow not clickable

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2, infowindow

Is it possible to make the infowindow of a marker not clickable? I was able to [make the Marker not clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17884401/google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-non-clickable) or make the infowindow dissapear with a click

```
OnInfoWindowClickListener InfoWindowListener = new OnInfoWindowClickListener(){ 
    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
        marker.hideInfoWindow();
    }};
```

but none of them is really what I want. I can image that creating a custom Infowindow can be the solution, but I'm wondering if there is a faster/easier way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:
Just create a HashMap with the marker.getId() and the "clickable" or not "clickable" as the second value.

So whenever you add a mapper in your map just insert:

```
clickableMarkers.put(currentMarker.getId(), CLICKABLE);
```

and in your InfoWindowClick method do the following check:

```
if (clickableMarkers.get(marker.getId()).equals(CLICKABLE)){
    //Do whatever you want with clickable info windows
}else{
    //Do whatever you want with non clickable info windows
}
```