# Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps - Need to place custom pins very close together using a Map_Clicked. Seems to be padding problem

Tags: c#, dictionary, xamarin, pins

I have custom pins set up for Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps. I am reading them from existing .png icons which are transparent and do not have padding using the BitmapDescriptorFactory.

My code is much like this article -> https://nerd-corner.com/how-to-add-custom-icon-pins-to-google-maps-xamarin-app/

The problem? I need to place them almost on top of each other. There seems to be padding around the pin that does not let me click and place the pin almost on top of the other pin.

I have tried setting the Z-index dynamically.
I have tried the Flat option. I'm not quite sure what it does.
I tried to set the Icon.View.Margin to a zero Thickness

Comment: Perhaps [make the markers non-clickable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17884401/199364), while you place the new one. [One answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58072282/199364) says don't set `Marker.title`. [Another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17887439/199364) suggests using a `GroundOverlay` instead of a marker. Bottom line: Give user a way to say that they want to add a new marker, then alter what is on the map, so they can do that.

Comment: The markers are not clickable because I do not add the pin click event. With Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps you have to set the label. Right now I have the label set to an empty string. User does have the choice to add the marker. They just want it really close to the other marker. I did think about the circle. I might make one of them a circle and try that.