# Ignore onMarkerClick and make onMapClick programmatically in android

Tags: click, google-maps-android-api-2, marker

I have map and marker on it. I need to do when user pushes this marker or pushes near this marker that  app wil do "onMapClick listener" and return me coordinates of click instead of "onMarkerClick". It is somehow possible to ignore marker click for one marker and make onMapClick instead?

I tried this, but it don't do anything:

> mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener(){
>
> ```
>       @Override
>       public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {             
>            if(arg0.getSnippet().equals("bad_marker")){
>
>                    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener() {        
>                   @Override
>                   public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {                             
>                       mapClick(latLng); 
>                   }       
>              });
>              }});
> ```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Also, I wouldn't set a listener inside another listener in the way you did. Do you need to get the marker position you have just clicked? If so, there's a method for that: getPosition().

Comment: I tried this method - but it returns clicked marker coordinates, but I need accurate click coordinates. Because click can be near marker position, but it still cals onMarkerClickListener()

Comment: I have the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15401988/disable-onmarkerclicklistener-completely-in-maps-api-v2

Answer (score 0):

Save your marker in a class variable, so you have reference to it.

Then set an `OnMarkerClickListener` and check if arg0 is your marker: if so, do what you have to do if the user clicks on that marker.

Also set an `setOnMapClickListener` and check if latLng given to you by `onMapClick` is close to the position of your marker. You have your marker as class variable, so you can get its position and check it against the position on the map where the user clicked.

Comment: This does not solve the problem onMapClick is never called if OnMarkerClick is called.