# How to disable marker click event?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am developing an simple app, where I already displayed marker title with `mrkr.showInfoWindow()` but I don't want user to tap again that marker. How to disable clicking event of particular marker ?

This is how I tried.

```
   Marker marker = gMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(location
                    .getLatitude(), location.getLongitude())).title("I am here").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.mrk1)));
            marker.showInfoWindow();
//how to use marker.setClickable here or somthing here.?
```

How to display that infowindow()/title of my marker throughout my application ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can set onMarkerClickListener in GoogleMap object

Java:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            return true;
        }
    });
```

In Kotlin, you can simply do:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener { true }
```

Comment: If you want to disable the market click event then I guess this is not the correct answer.

Comment: it worked. but i have multiple markers. can disabling of one particular marker clicking is possible.?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html doc says that method returns true if we don't want default behavior

Comment: You can get marker's Id, title etc.. See here http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html Filter markers as you want

Answer (score 9):

It is clear by this point 3 years later, that there is no way to let marker clicks pass through to be handled by the map itself (OnMapClickListener). Markers will always intercept this event, although you can disable the default behavior from the click (as the answer above shows). The following is posted in case it can help someone still needing a better solution.

To work around this limitation, there are two options. I have implemented both, and can clean up and share the code on request.

1.) Create a GroundOverlay Bitmap that has the waypoints which you don't want to handle painted onto it. You use the GoogleMap's Projection object to convert from screen Points to LatLng, and calculate where to position the Bitmap to have the waypoints appear in the correct place. Its fairly complicated to handle rotation, map padding, and a few other issues. As you zoom in, the waypoint markers do grow in size, and then in the onCameraIdle event, you re-create the bitmap, and re-position the GroundOverlay if necessary. This is the method I am using in production. Panning, rotating and zooming are all super smooth, and as Ground Overlays can be set to handle or not handle taps, it solves the problem. I was not able to figure out how to make this work with tilt. The waypoints themselves do not stay facing North during rotation, but can be rotated upright when the GroundOverlay is re-created. There is a short pause/non-responsiveness of the map after the onCameraIdle causes the re-creation of the ground overlay.

2.) Create a View object that covers the entire screen, and paints the waypoint markers in the onDraw method of the view. Again, use the GoogleMap's projection object to calculate where to paint the markers. Call invalidate() on the view when in the onCameraMove event, so the markers are re-drawn at their new screen positions. The main advantage of this is simplicity. Rotation, tilt, map padding offsets are all handled for you. The main disadvantage is that if you invalidate on every onCameraMove event, it is a bit too cpu intensive (I presume) and the map panning / zooming can become choppy. If you invalidate every 3 or 5 move events, then the waypoints appear to be bouncing as you pan/zoom as they aren't repainted in their new position frequently enough. There is no delay at the end of the map move, though. Ultimately, with 100-200 waypoints on the map, the "while-panning" performance issues were too noticeable for me.

Hope this helps someone. Let me know if you need some code help.

Comment: A 3rd option is to intercept map touches with a containing ViewGroup and use Projection to determine where the user touched.  It all depends on what you are trying to do though.  I found this answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14013002/google-maps-android-api-v2-detect-touch-on-map

Comment: Another 4th option is to use `Activity.dispatchTouchEvent` and convert screen position coordinates to map ones

Comment: I've provided a solution, shown below - my rant caused me to think up a better way :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [onMarkerClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.html) for this like below,

```
mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener( new OnMarkerClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick ( Marker marker )
    {
        // do nothing
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried with returning true. its worked. But i have multiple markers.it disabled all other markers click event.. Can disabling of one particular marker is possible.

Comment: `true` means it allows you to click then how it can be possible that it disables the click event  ?

Comment: i also wondered but it is working. it disabled all marker's click event.

Comment: return false, is wrong. to stop user click event we need to set it to true.

Answer (score 0):

@mstenroos Provides one solution. Here is another. Basically, onMarkerClick ALWAYS overrides MapClick. If the user touches the map in a blank area you get the MapClick listener. If they touch near a marker (which may touch in a transparent icon area - so the user may not realise they are touching an icon) then you get MarkerClick. What's the problem you ask? Well, MarkerClick doesn't give you the point on the map and, as I said, this may not even be on the visible part of the icon marker. You may also want to handle overlapping markers and MarkerClick will only give you one event and one marker - there is no pass through like there is with components. The only pass through (if you return false in the MarkerClick listener) is the default map action of centring the marker and popping up a dialogue.

Using Kotlin/Compose I solved this thus. I first set a pointerInteropFilter on the Google Map:

```
modifier = Modifier
                    .pointerInteropFilter { motionEvent ->
                        when (motionEvent.action) {
                            MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                                println("ACTION DOWN")
                                viewModel.mapPointerDown = Point(motionEvent.x.toInt(), motionEvent.y.toInt())
                                false
                            }
                            else -> false // Let other events pass through to the underlying map
                        }
                    }
```

in which I save the DOWN location in my ViewModel, and then let the DOWN pass through to the map so that map gestures will work.

Then I set my listeners on the map:

```
fun setupMapAndListeners(theMap: GoogleMap) {

        // Set up the listeners on the map.
        theMap.setOnMarkerClickListener {
            // perform action using the mapPointerDown location
            true }
        theMap.setOnMapClickListener {
            // perform action using the mapPointerDown location
        }
...
```

And voila! we have the position and can do what we want with it. We can keep it as X/Y positions or convert it using Projection to a lat/lng. We can check it against our map markers to see which has been tapped or not and we can choose to ignore certain map markers or distinguish between overlapping markers. And as we drive off into the sunset of capturing events, we give Google the middle finger for their ridiculous way of handling map events.

I hope this helps someone and saves them the two hours of pure frustration I've just gone through as to why onMapClick was not working all of the time.