# Is it possible to have onMapClick() called instead of onMarkerClick()?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a google map in my app and I handle clicks on it. Everything is fine but if I click on a marker or really close to it `onMarkerClick()` is called, not `onMapClick()` and then I don't have the exact location of the place I tapped because `marker.getPosition()` returns the center point of the marker what's not the same.

Is it possible to disable `onMarkerClick()` and have `onMapClick()` called even if I click on a marker?

Comment: post your code?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you still want the marker to be clickable, but only when you click on it (on its center), not when you click really close to it. Am I right ?

Comment: No, I want the map to be clicable even in that place where the marker is shown. Now the marker consumes that event.

Comment: You don't want to react anymore to marker click (always ?)

Comment: Have you tried without declaring a MarkerClickListener ?

Comment: Yes, I tried. Again what I want is handling onMapClick() always event if the click is on or close to the marker.

Comment: @Giks91 have a look to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41867025/5914654)

Answer (score 0):

Return true for disabling marker click event

```
googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

For getting click on maps use this listener on `onMapReady`

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng arg0)
    {
        Log.v("onMapClick", "Yea worked!");
    }
});
}
```

Complete code

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-34, 151);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));

    googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Map clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Marker disabled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but that's exactly what I did and the place where the marker is shown is not clicable but I expect onMapClick() to be called.

Comment: It's an open source project the class is here https://github.com/opendatakit/collect/blob/master/collect_app/src/main/java/org/odk/collect/android/map/GoogleMapFragment.java

Comment: Now there is no setOnMarkerClickListener there so the click is handled in a default way (a menu is shown on the bottom). If I add your solution nothing happens because it's consumed but still onMapClick() is not called then. So maybe it's not possible at all?

Comment: I did that and then the marker is not clickable indeed but still onMapClick() not called if I click on it.

Comment: can you try adding that marker click listener inside map click listener

Comment: I would appreciate!

Comment: I tried and after clicking on the marker or close to it I can see "Marker disabled" what is fine but still onMapClick() is not called. Did you experience something different? I want onMapClick() to be called even in that case.