# How to disable android map marker click auto center

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-2

I am looking for a way to disable my map fragment's auto centre on selected marker functionality. I still want the markers InfoWindow to show up, but just not centre the entire map on the marker I have selected.

Comment: It is working properly, it is exactly proper solution.
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15925319/how-to-disable-android-map-marker-click-auto-center?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Take a look at the following post:

[Don't snap to marker after click in android map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497734/dont-snap-to-marker-after-click-in-android-map-v2)

There is a method given there by **@DMan**, basically you need to consume the `OnMarkerClick` event and override the default behavior:

```
// Since we are consuming the event this is necessary to
// manage closing openned markers before openning new ones
Marker lastOpenned = null;

mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new OnMarkerClickListener() {
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
    // Check if there is an open info window
    if (lastOpenned != null) {
        // Close the info window
        lastOpenned.hideInfoWindow();

        // Is the marker the same marker that was already open
        if (lastOpenned.equals(marker)) {
            // Nullify the lastOpenned object
            lastOpenned = null;
            // Return so that the info window isn't openned again
            return true;
        } 
    }

    // Open the info window for the marker
    marker.showInfoWindow();
    // Re-assign the last openned such that we can close it later
    lastOpenned = marker;

    // Event was handled by our code do not launch default behaviour.
    return true;
}
});
```

Comment: @Emil Adz,I have used the same logic but still i got map move onMarker Click;

Comment: @AravinthaBashyam.c if you are returning true at the end on this method then it shouldn't move, and why is the down-vote?

Comment: @AravinthaBashyam.c I think you had written setOnMarkerOnclick many times,

Comment: What do you mean, the answer is perfectly fine and been upvoted by 5 users, if it doesn't work for you then you are doing something wrong, open a new question with your code and I will try to help you.

Answer (score 36):

Simple way:

1. Implement setOnMarkerClickListener()
2. Return 'TRUE' to prevent GoogleMap by default moves the map center to the marker.

Example:

```
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(
    new OnMarkerClickListener() {
        boolean doNotMoveCameraToCenterMarker = true;
        public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
            //Do whatever you need to do here ....
            return doNotMoveCameraToCenterMarker;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 8):

Very Simple:

Use below code for implement setOnMarkerClickListener().

```
@Override
public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {

    marker.showInfoWindow(); // show info window

    return true; // can't move map by this
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Simple. Add `moveOnMarkerPress` prop to `MapView` and set it to false.

```
 <MapView
      moveOnMarkerPress={false}
>
```

Comment: This seems to be for ReactNative, not for the native Android SDK

Comment: This is for react-native-map and it is working.