# Android Google Map - Clicked marker opens new activity or bigger window

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I've been searching for help on implementing OnMarkerClickListener but nothing I've found has worked. This is my marker below and when clicked it only changes colour(light blue). I'm looking for it to open a bigger window so I can put in more info. Is this possible?

```
     googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(49.378,-0.3904))
    .title("Hello World")
    .snippet("This is my test app")    
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));
```

The marker works fine above on my Map but now I would like to click on the marker and for it to open a new activity/page or a bigger window, what ever is easier to work with. As I am a real novice at making apps, If anyone who has successfully got a working example please could you put up a link or some code.

Thanks in advance!

***Edit:***

From the tutorial that was suggested I have changed some of the MainActivity.java.

I've added in OnMarkerClickListener and have chosen to add unimplemented methods to the Public Class

```
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener, OnMarkerClickListener {
```

Underneath private void setUpMap() I have added to my code: private Marker myMarker, the setonMarkerclick listener and myMarker =,  :

```
       private Marker myMarker;
         {
googlemap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

myMarker = googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(new LatLng(LatLng))
    .title("Hello World")
    .snippet("My First App")    
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_ORANGE)));

 }
```

In the unimplemented method at the bottom I have:

```
   @Override
   public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub 

return false;
```

What do I need to change in the public Boolean OnMarkerClick part?
I'm not getting any errors but its just not working. What else do I have to add in or change?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: pose more code where you declare the `OnMarkerClickListener`

Answer (score 31):

Marker click events

[Don't snap to marker after click in android map v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14497734/dont-snap-to-marker-after-click-in-android-map-v2)

Quoting from the above post

You can use an `OnMarkerClickListener` to listen for click events on the marker. To set this listener on the map, call GoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(OnMarkerClickListener). When a user clicks on a marker, onMarkerClick(Marker) will be called and the marker will be passed through as an argument. This method returns a boolean that indicates whether you have consumed the event (i.e., you want to suppress the default behavior). If it returns false, then the default behavior will occur in addition to your custom behavior. The default behavior for a marker click event is to show its info window (if available) and move the camera such that the marker is centered on the map.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener.

Use OnMarkerClickListener on your marker.

Check the link for code snippets

[Google Maps API v2: How to make markers clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226453/google-maps-api-v2-how-to-make-markers-clickable)

Example: Works on my phone

```
    Marker source, destination;
    GoogleMap mMap;

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
    source = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(sc)
            .title("MyHome")
            .snippet("Bangalore")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));

    destination = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(lng)
            .title("MapleBear Head Office")
            .snippet("Jayanager")
            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.pin)));

    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
        if (marker.getTitle().equals("MyHome")) // if marker source is clicked
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, marker.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// display toast
        return true;
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added in the code from the tutorial but there has been no changes so far, I can't click on the markers and it doesn't open anything. I have made an edit to my question and have included the updated code. Please have a look when you get the chance.

Comment: @user1977908 well if you see the accepted answer in the link it should work. Are you using info widow and trying to click on the same?. Also make your return statement in onMarkerClick to true

Comment: I tried this code but I couldn't actually click on a marker afterwards. Also when I added in OnMarkerClickListener in the "public class MainActivity extends Activity" it asked me to add unimplemented methods so I had two @override public boolean onMarkerClick. This didn't really work aswell and couldn't get rid of one.

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay not entirely. i have added a cope snippet of my own.

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay i am not sure if even copied it from the link which i normally don't do. I always check the docs. any way i added whats necessary. duplciating answers is wrong if you copy paste and add some of your own its not wrong.

Comment: no issue sir i am removing my comments, please do not feel bad, please do not mind, please do not feel that i interfere yours work!! sorry

Comment: @JiteshUpadhyay no feel bad if you think or sense something is wrong don't hesitate to flag the answer in which case it will be dealt appropriately by moderators.

Comment: Hello every body please any body tell me how can i transfer the the details of markers to new activity by applying click on listener on the marker

Comment: @NikhilSingh you can see the documentaion of what details you can get with Marker and use intent to pass the details to new activity. https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker. Do your stuff in onMarkerClick

Comment: @Raghunandan thanx fr ur advice Sir I will go through the link u mentioned

Answer (score 10):

This code handles the maker click event and loads a new layout (XML) with some information:

```
/**
 * adding individual markers, displaying text on on marker click on a
 * bubble, action of on marker bubble click
 */
private final void addLocationsToMap() {
    int i = 0;
    for (Stores store : storeList) {
        LatLng l = new LatLng(store.getLatitude(), store.getLongtitude());

        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(l)
                .title(store.getStoreName())
                .snippet("" + i)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN));
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        ++i;
    }

    googleMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

            try {
                popUpWindow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Stores store = storeList.get(Integer.parseInt(marker
                        .getSnippet()));

                // set details
                email.setText(store.getEmail());
                phoneNo.setText(store.getPhone());
                address.setText(store.getAddress());

                // setting test value to phone number
                tempString = store.getPhone();
                SpannableString spanString = new SpannableString(tempString);
                spanString.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0,
                        spanString.length(), 0);
                phoneNo.setText(spanString);

                // setting test value to email
                tempStringemail = store.getEmail();

                SpannableString spanString1 = new SpannableString(tempStringemail);
                spanString1.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, spanString1.length(), 0);
                email.setText(spanString1);

                storeLat = store.getLatitude();
                storelng = store.getLongtitude();

            } catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                Log.e("ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException", " Occured");
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Comment: would you mind including the code that actually defines the var 'popUpWindow' ?

Comment: @TharakaNirmana.. what is popUpWindow here? plz define in your answer?

Comment: it is a linear / relative layout that has email, phoneNo etc.

Answer (score 6):

If you need the event Click in a market,this code it's the solution.

```
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;


mGoogleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker arg0) {
                if(arg0 != null && arg0.getTitle().equals(markerOptions2.getTitle().toString())); // if marker  source is clicked
                    Toast.makeText(menu.this, arg0.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// display toast
                return true;
            }

        });
```

**Good Luck**

Comment: where do I put this code ? "cannot resolved symbol setOnMarkerClickListener"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use of OnInfoWindowClickListener, it will trigger when you click on marker and then the snippet.
Use setTag to attach any object with the marker.

```
    Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
    marker.setTag(myObject);
```

and the listener

```
      mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {

         MyObject mo =  (MyObject )arg0.getTag();


           }
       });
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code to used for Kotlin when user click on **marker** to perform any action

```
        googleMap!!.setOnMarkerClickListener { marker ->
            if (marker.title == "Marker1")
                Log.d(TAG, "Clicked on Marker1")
            true
        }
```